# Making a request for JSON data with Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

It's probably just me, but I'm really having a bad time with Angular documentation. For example, I'm trying to understand how can I read(running loops on it and pull some data from it across the application) a JSON file and I found this link of Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

They're posting the following code, but don't say where it should go(to what file):

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
}
```

Side note: I put my JSON file inside of the assets folder and I want to use the data from it across several components.

Side note two: I would really appreciate your help with how to deal with the documentation, perhaps I'm missing something? It is very hard for a newbie to understand what goes where.

Thanks

Comment: @wprzechodzen, thank you for trying to edit, but `angularjs` has more subscribers than `angular`. Make an edit without deleting the `angularjs` and I'll approve it with pleasure. You said in the edit that `Problem connected with Angular - not AngularJS` - can you please tell me what's the difference? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

```
// version without map

    @Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:  Add **.json** if it's a json file
    this.http.get('/api/items.json').subscribe(data => {
      // Read the result field from the JSON response.
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
}

// with map
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

 @Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api/items.json')
     .map((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .subscribe((data) => {
     this.results = data['results'];       
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should this go, Rajan? What file?

Comment: This should go in the same file your are working on above code. Can you please, clarify if your are requesting api with json file or api request only.
If you are trying to get the .json file from server just add .json in your api request.

Comment: I'm not even sure it's an API request. I simply want to get data from JSON file. What I have right now is one default component - the root one. Should I put this code iside the 'app.component.ts'? As for right now, it has this code: `export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}`

Comment: So I should delete it and replace with the one that "implements OnInit", correct?

Comment: Ok, tried that - it gives me an error while "ng serve". It says "Cannot find name 'OnInit'", "Cannot find name 'HttpClient'." twice.

Comment: I'm quite not sure how you've configured app.

Comment: As it says on the documentation: ng new my-app-name

Comment: Oooooh... I got it! I had to install a new component, and not trying to perform it on the root one! I'm on it baby! :) Will try it now